What symmetries does the 'Chebyshev' three-term recurrence relation have?
If $T_n$ solves the 'Chebyshev' like three-term recurrence relation $T_{n+1}(x) = 2x T_n(x) - T_{n-1}(x)$, then what other solutions can be derived from this?
I explicitly do not want to fix the initial or boundary conditions $T_0$ and $T_1$.
First, index translation: if $T_n$ is a solution, so is $T_{n+k}$ for a fixed integer $k$.
Second, it is easy to see that sums of $T_n$, e.g. $T_n(x)+T_{n+1}(x)$, will also be solutions.
Third, actually, functional factors that do not depend on $n$ work, i.e. $p(x) T_n(x)$ will be a solution for any function $p(x)$.
Fourth, 'coordinate' sign change: if $T_n$ is a solution, so is $(-1)^nT_n(-x)$.
What else is there? Anything? Or is that it? Any other $f(x) T_n(F(x))$ option?
What about index sign change: If $T_n$ is a solution, so is $n\to T_{-n}$?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The following does not directly answer your general question, but completely unveils the structure of the space of sequences which satisfy the 3-terms recurrence relation
$$\forall n\ge1\quad T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x).$$
For such a sequence $(T_n)$, a closed form formula is
$$\forall n\ge2\quad T_n(x)=U_{n-1}(x)T_1(x)-U_{n-2}(x)T_0(x),$$ where $(U_n)$ is the sequence of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.
The proof (by 2-step induction) is straightforward, using that $(U_n)$ statisfies the same 3-terms recurrence relation. It is even simpler to prove that $\forall n\ge\color{red}0\quad T_n(x)=U_{n-1}(x)T_1(x)-U_{n-2}(x)T_0(x)$, if you augment beforehand the sequence $(U_n)$ with two more "initial values": $U_{-1}(x)=0$ and $U_{-2}(x)=-1$ (which are compatible with the usual ones $U_0(x)=1$, $U_1(x)=2x$, via the 3-terms recurrence relation).
As you already noticed, the converse is obvious, i.e. given $P(x),Q(x)$, the sequence $(T_n)$ defined by $T_0=P$, $T_1=Q$, and $\forall n\ge2\quad T_n(x)=U_{n-1}(x)Q(x)-U_{n-2}(x)P(x)$, satisfies the same 3-terms recurrence relation.

many thanks for sharing; I was indeed not aware of this simple and efficient way of calculating any solution given $T_0$ and $T_1$ using the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind... and illustrates the uniqueness of the 'fundamental' choice of the $U_n$s
